# M M 1 Queuing Model where $\lambda_n=0$ after some point

Tags: markov-chains, queueing-theory

I have an m/m/1 queue with arrival rates $\lambda_0=3, \lambda_1=2,\lambda_2=1$ and for all $n>2$ we have $\lambda_n=0$. With constant service rates of $\mu=2$

I need here to calculate the stationary distribution for the above system, however when doing this I run into a problem. Namely that when we try to calculate the distribution we get

$\pi_{1}=\pi_{0},$
$\pi_{2}=2\pi_{0},$
$\pi_{3}=4\pi_{0},$
$\pi_{3}=\pi_{2},$
$\pi_{4}=\pi_{3}$

so $\pi_i=\pi_{i+1}$ for all $i\geq2 \Rightarrow \pi_0 = 0$ and then that all probabilities are zero. I feel as though I am doing something wrong here but I can't put my finger on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: This queue is not M/M/1 anymore!

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean exactly, could you please expand this further

Comment: For [M/M/1 queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue), the arrival process should be Poisson with a constant rate $\lambda$, not $\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\ldots$

Comment: So since our basic theory is built upon a Poisson model with constant rate, we cannot use the conventional method for calculating the stationary distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your calculations are correct. Given the rates that you have,
$$ 0 \rightleftharpoons^3_2 1 \rightleftharpoons^2_2 2 \rightleftharpoons^1_2 3,$$
the  [transition rate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix) would be:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
2& -4 &2 &0\\
0 & 2 & -3 &1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$
The transition matrix for the Markov chain is:
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{2}{4}& 0 &\frac{2}{4} &0\\
0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 &\frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the equation $\pi P= \pi$ has only one (invalid) trivial solution $\pi=[\pi_0, \pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3]=\vec{0}$. Hence, an stationary distribution does not exist.